# Uploading a file in PHP won´t work

Tags: php, file, upload

So I am having an issue with getting my file to upload to where I want
it. It executes everything but it doesnt upload the file. It just
says:

> There was something wrong with your file.

Here is my code:
Thanks for the help!

```
<p>The file must be an image and less than 2 MB.</p>
<form action="filerupp.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p>Choose file:<br/>
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload image" name="submit"></p>
</form>
<p>Files are <a href='pictures'>here</a>.</p>
```

And here is my PHP Code:

```
$target_dir = "pictures/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "<p>The File is an image" . $check["mime"] . ".<br/>";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "<p>The File is not an image.<br/>";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "<p>Sorry, the file already exists.<br/>";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, the file är för stor.<br/>";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF.<br/>";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file cannot be uploaded.</p>";

// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "<p>The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded and is <a href='pictures'>here</a>.</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Sorry, there was something wrong with your file.</p>";
    }
}
```

Comment: check the permission of folder

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php follow this link or may be check your folder permissions where you upload image. If not solved contact me . skype: harryr891

Comment: Is this on Linux or Windows?

Comment: Do not vandalize your post by undoing helpful edits. Blockquote formatting is *only* for quotations, not the entire text of your question. "[SOLVED]" never belongs in titles here; the system has other ways of indicating that a question has been answered (the green checkmark: you already found it). If you are uncomfortable with the idea that [posts are collaboratively edited](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), this may not be the right website for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured out the issue thanks to a comment I saw. Thanks to all who tried to help. Nothing was wrong with my code it was the permission on my own freakin folder. I had checked the servers permissions and they were okay but I hadnt checked my own folder -_- Thanks tho, problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

The filesize upload limit of this script is only about half a magabyte so likley your image is larger than that.  Even 2 Megabytes is a very small limit, probably better to make it 10 Megabytes.